# Как взять определенное значение из базы mongodb?nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Всем привет. Вот у меня есть определенные данные в mongodb например :

```
{
   "_id": "56647d86d9742e5c1cce4023",
   "longurl": "http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html",
   "shorturl": "KoQrG",
   "__v": 0
}
```

и вот есть гет запрос:

```
app.get('/url/:url', function(req,res){
    urls.find({shorturl : req.params.url}, function(err,result){ //urls - это сама база с данными.
        if (err) res.json(err);
        else res.redirect(result.longurl); //вот тут я хочу перейти на другую страницу
    });
});
```

Так вот как я пытаюсь перейти туда, то мне пишет

> На этой странице обнаружена циклическая переадресация

Пытался просто сделать так `res.send(result.longurl)`, но оно ничего не выводит, а когда просто `res.send(result)`, то выводит все значения этого поля (_id, longurl,shorturl,_v).
Но мне надо обратится именно к longurl и взять его значение. Как это сделать?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: очевидно же, что ты уже на этой странице. выведи в лог req.params.url и result.longurl

Comment: ну при result.longurl вывело undefined оно не может почему то взять longurl из базы, вообще меня должно переадресовать на ту страницу что хранится в longurl.

Comment: как так "не может взять". ты же сам пишешь "а когда просто res.send(result) то выводит все значения этого поля(_id,longurl,shorturl,_v)"

Comment: да оно выводит все поля которые есть вместе с тем что передается при запросе когда пишешь просто result, но мне надо взять именно значения longurl от туда, а оно возвращает undefinded когда пишешь result.longurl . Вот я хочу из этого longurl":"mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html получить только ссылку

Comment: `result[0].longurl`, кстати, в жтом случае лучше использовать findOne вместо find

Answer (score 1):

## Причина

#### Что есть что

`result` - массив,
`result[0]` - первый найденный документа,

`result[0].longurl` - полный веб-путь первого совпавшего документа

#### Откуда циклическая переадресация

`result.longurl` = `undefined`, при редиректе оно превращается в `''`, трактуется браузером как относительный адрес и воспринимается как "текущая страница". Браузер запрашивает текущую страницу и получает редирект на нее же. Это и есть циклическая переадресация.

#### Что помогло запутаться

Вас ввела в заблуждение конструкция `res.send(result)`.

`result` - массив из одного элемента, `res.send()` приведет его к строке `{}`, опустив квадратные скобки массива. Если бы использовали `res.json()` - он привел бы его к виду `[{}]` и ошибку вы бы нашли сразу.

### Решение

Пользователь [norbornen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472407/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b7%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-mongodbnodejs#comment531186_472407) в комменариях прав. Вам вместо:

```
res.redirect(result.longurl);// = undefined
```

нужно делать:

```
res.redirect(result[0].longurl);// = "http://mongoo..."
```